# Concatenar variable con texto en SQL SERVER para asignar valor dinámicamente

Tags: sql-server, variables

Tengo varias variables con el mismo nombre pero se diferencia al final con un numero, y tengo que asignar un valor luego pero dependiendo de una variable de control numérica así le asigno el valor,  para no tener que hacer una cantidad de `if` anidados quiero saber como logro hacer esto:

```
  @variable1;
  @variable2;
  @variable3;
  @control = 2;

  select @variable+@control = 'informacion';
```

Algo así deseo lograr se que no es posible tal cual como lo escribí pero en otros lenguajes si se puede, como para asignar ese valor así dinámicamente

Comment: hasta donde sé, no es posible hacer lo que deseas, por lo que entiendo, quieres asignar a variable2 el valor 'información', cosa que es imposible, me parece que forzosamente ocuparás hacerlo con if.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible pero bastante "trabajoso"

```
DECLARE @SQL        NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @control    INT
DECLARE @VARIABLE1  VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @VARIABLE2  VARCHAR(255)

SELECT  @CONTROL    = 2

SELECT  @SQL = '
SELECT @VARIABLE' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CONTROL) + ' = ''información'''

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, 
        N'@VARIABLE1 VARCHAR(255) OUTPUT, @VARIABLE2 VARCHAR(255) OUTPUT',
        @VARIABLE1  = @VARIABLE1 OUTPUT,
        @VARIABLE2  = @VARIABLE2 OUTPUT

SELECT  @VARIABLE1 AS '@VARIABLE1', 
        @VARIABLE2 AS '@VARIABLE2'
```

La idea es crear una sentencia `@SQL` dinámica en función de la variable `@control`, la cual luego evaluaremos mediante `sp_executesql`

La salida:

```
@VARIABLE1  @VARIABLE2
----------  -----------
NULL        información
```

Como verás requiere bastante trabajo para poder hacerlo, y lamentablemente no vas a evitar declarar cada una de las variables en la llamada a `sp_executesql`, pero la verdad no sé si hay otra forma que no sea un `CASE`, por ej:

```
DECLARE @control    INT
DECLARE @VARIABLE1  VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @VARIABLE2  VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Valor      VARCHAR(255)

SELECT  @CONTROL    = 2

SELECT  @Valor = 'información'
SELECT  @VARIABLE1 = CASE WHEN @CONTROL = 1 THEN @Valor ELSE NULL END,
        @VARIABLE2 = CASE WHEN @CONTROL = 2 THEN @Valor ELSE NULL END

SELECT  @VARIABLE1 AS '@VARIABLE1', 
        @VARIABLE2 AS '@VARIABLE2'
```

Answer (score -1):

No exactamente como lo esperias pero aqui un intento:

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE @VARIABLE2 VARCHAR(40)

SELECT @VARIABLE = 'HOLA', @VARIABLE2 = 'MUNDO!'
```

Comment: Alguna explicacion del porque el No Util?

Comment: El problema @Einer Santana, es que no resuelve la pregunta, lo que el op preguntaba es si tenía forma de redirigir dinámicamente la asignación de una variable